# Using Scanner.in with java Applet

Tags: java, applet, java.util.scanner, draw

so please excuse any informalities.

I've successfully calculated the areas and volume of a cylinder using scanned values for the radius and height, but now want to build an applet which gives a graphical representation of the cylinder whilst showing the values below.

I've done half of this: I've built an applet which draws a cylinder and prints information below it (using drawOval, drawLine and drawString) -- but the varibles have to be constant. I can't use scanner.in while using java Applet. Is there anyway around this, some other method or library which I should use?

Code below:--

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
* Draw a cylinder using radius and height; and calculate base, lateral and total area; and    volume.
* vrsn 0.1 draw text data below cylinder
* @author (thkoby) 
* @vrsn 0.1 dt. Jan 6, 2015
* @vrsn 0.0 dt. Jan. 5, 2015
*/
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class cyl extends Applet {

double Pi = 3.1415926; //global value for constant pi

public void paint (Graphics g) {
  int bottX; //x pos. bottom cylinder
  int bottY;
  int topX; //x pos. top cylinder
  int topY;

  double bArea; //base area
  double tArea; //total area
  double lArea; //lateral area
  double vol; //volume

  double rad = 10; //radius
  double height = 20; //height

  int r = (int) rad;
  int h = (int) height;

  int d = 2*r; //diameter

  int fontSize = 12;

  bArea = baseArea(rad);
  tArea = totalArea(rad,height);
  lArea = lateralArea(rad,height);
  vol = volume(rad,height);

  //x,y pos. for bottom oval
  bottX = 20;
  bottY = 20 + h;
  //x,y pos. for top oval  
  topX = 20;
  topY = 20;

  //Graphical representation of the cylinder
  g.drawOval (topX, topY, d, r); //radius is used to give angled appearance
  g.drawOval (bottX, bottY, d, r);
  g.drawLine (topX,topY+(r/2),bottX,bottY+(r/2));
  g.drawLine (topX+d,topY+(r/2),bottX+d,bottY+(r/2));

  //text information below cylinder
  g.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.drawString("Radius: "+r, 20, 40+h+r);
  g.drawString("Height: "+h, 20, 54+h+r);
  g.drawString("Base Area: "+bArea, 20, 68+h+r);
  g.drawString("Total Area: "+tArea, 20, 82+h+r);
  g.drawString("Lateral Area: "+lArea, 20, 96+h+r);
  g.drawString("Volume: "+vol, 20, 110+h+r);
}

public double baseArea(double rad) { //base area = radius squared * pi
    return (rad*rad)*Pi;
}
public double totalArea(double rad,double height) { //total area = 2pi * radius * (height +   radius)
    return 2*Pi*rad*(height + rad);
}
public double lateralArea(double rad, double height) { //lateral area = 2pi * radius * height
    return 2*Pi*rad*height;
}
double volume(double rad, double height) { //volume = 2pi * radius squared * height
    return Pi*(rad*rad)*height;
}

}
```

Comment: use some dialog for user input. Or use non-applet Swing or JavaFX components for the visualization.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: `double Pi = 3.1415926; //global value for constant pi`  See [`Math.PI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI) - *"The double value that is closer than any other to **pi,** the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter."*